# Rendering graph in canvas js using external json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, canvasjs

I am trying to render graphs using `canvas.js`. The charts need to be rendered from an external JSON source, which is hosted at this website

http://gsx2json.com/api?id=1vc7wCjNXK39HMEYDkOJRMhQGPJpxMu4MJgTsydyLats

The objective is to, graph a chart from 2 values in the JSON data (ie example, timestamp vs latitude)

This is the code, which I have so far:

```
$.getJSON("http://gsx2json.com/apiid=1vc7wCjNXK39HMEYDkOJRMhQGPJpxMu4MJgTsydyLats", function addData(data){


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    dataPoints.push({
        x: new Date(data[i].columns["timestamp"]),
        y: data[i].columns["latitude"]
    });
}

chart.render();


 // console.log(data.columns["timestamp"])

});
```

I am using the for loop to iterate thru the JSON object and then using JSON keys to access the data.

The data doesn't render, when I run this code. But, when I try to `console.log (data.columns["latitude"])` outside the for-loop, I am able to access the data which I need.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `let i` instead of `var i` in your for loop declaration

Comment: Nope, That didn't do anything!

Comment: Where is `dataPoints` defined in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise something like the following.

```
$(function(){
  var points = [];

  $.getJSON("http://gsx2json.com/api?id=1vc7wCjNXK39HMEYDkOJRMhQGPJpxMu4MJgTsydyLats&columns=false", function(d){
    $.each(d.rows, function(i, r){
      points.push({
        x: new Date(r.timestamp),
        y: r.latitude
      });
    });
  }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log("Ajax Error", status, error);
  });

  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    type: "line",
    data: [{
      dataPoints: points
    }]
  });
  chart.render();
});
```

This may encounter problems due to CORS.

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.

If this is the case, can try with `$.ajax()` and set `dataType` set to `jsonp`. Can also move to `fetch()` alternative.

Looking at the data returned, using `rows` might be easier, since you want the corresponding `timestamp` and `latitude`. The columns make this more difficult; you would have ti iterate both `columns.timestamp` array at the same time as `columns.latitude` array. Hence the `&columns=false` portion to the URL to help reduce data that needs to be passed back.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Your post helped me figure out the way to bypass CORS. I did use fetch as an alternative. As the person above wrote it'll be data.columns["timestamp][i] to read innermost json.

Comment: @gatata glad it's been helpful for you. I hope you consider upvoting the post and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are consoling data.columns[“latitude”] which is getting consoled whereas while parsing you are considering it as data[i].columns[“latitude”] which should ideally be data.columns[“latitude”][i]. Parsing the data received from JSON accordingly should work fine in this case.

```
function addData(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.columns["timestamp"].length; i++) {
    dataPoints.push({
      x: new Date(data.columns["timestamp"][i]),
      y: data.columns["latitude"][i]
    });
  }
  chart.render();
}

$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1eqjac", addData); //JSON has been stored in myjson.com due to CORS.
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnhk1xyt/)

Comment: Thanks for this! 
After this part got working , had to figure out a way so that CORS does not interfere. But really helpful solution!